# What do you use your QGIS plugins for?

Tags: qgis-plugins

I would like to know about QGIS plugins from a **user point of view**, because some plugin lack some user case, and one doesn't know what to do with it. I guess a lot of great plugin are under-used because people don't know what it does.

**Could you describe a plugin you like, what it's supposed to do, and specifically what you use it for and how you use it ? The best would be an answer = a plugin !**

My question is similar to [What QGIS plugins do you consider to be essential?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/19715/25139), but QGIS has evolved since and many features have been implemented and some plugin are depreciated, while great plugins appear every day.  I hope my question is not too broad. Any answer on any plugin can be useful in my opinion, even if the plugin is depreciated some day. I'll probably answer to my own question for some plugins I like and use a lot too.

Comment: This question is seeking to assemble a list of QGIS plugins and thus would be closed as too broad if there were not an existing duplicate.

Comment: Actually, one can get the list easily, here : https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/
But it's not the point of my question : it doesn't give a user explanation. The duplicate question is outdated. I'm not seeking for all plugin, but for plugins people use :) But I understand the too "broad" argument aswell.

Comment: Even if a list of plugins people use is a lot shorter than a list of all plugins I would expect it to still be a list of a lot more than 1.  Questions here should always be seeking one answer.  We have multiple answers available to provide opportunity for variants on that one answer.  Questions seeking multiple correct answers at their outset are too broad for focussed Q&A.

Comment: If a Q&A is outdated then its question and/or answers need to be improved so that they are not.  Asking the same or a very similar question is not an alternative to ongoing curation of earlier content.

Comment: Questions seeking opinions are off-topic here in the Question/Answer database. You could engage in such a discussion in the chat feature of this exchange, but is not well-utilized, so the chat session may not be very rewarding.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers ! ....I'm still learning the "how to do things right" on gis stack :) Sorry for that. Shall I remove my question ?

Comment: There's no need to delete your question but it is your choice. Having some questions that illustrate question types that are unsuitable for focussed Q&A can be useful.

Comment: OK, I'll leave it. I suppose the answer below could be useful to someone in any case :)

Answer (score 1):

**Maps Printer**

**Basic description** : This very useful plugin is made to help you export in a clic a bunch of composer, including atlas based composer, instead of opening them one by one and exporting things manually. In short, a batch export composers within a QGS project. Language is french but the way it works it fairly simple and can be understood easily.

[image: Batch export composers]

**User case** : We used it here in gis.stack.exchange to create [a script allowing a user to batch export all composers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/207307/25139), from a bunch of QGS files in a folder, a real time saving plugin and script combination. It works on QGIS 2.18.

[image: batch export QGS]